# Can't import the Svg library in elm?

Tags: import, elm

Trying to use `Svg` and `Svg.Attributes`. Getting the error message

```
I cannot find module 'Svg'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
    * Mispelled the module name
    * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
```

I'm certain that there aren't any spelling errors because I copy and pasted the imports from a tutorial. Where do I install this library?

The tutorial I'm going through is the one elm-lang.org, specifically the section on time.

Comment: Can you post the full code? Or perhaps the link to the tutorial where you copied the code?

Comment: Is `elm-lang/svg` in the `elm-package.json`? (try `elm package install elm-lang/svg` in the project directory)

Comment: @robertjlooby thanks that worked, you might was well turn that into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `elm-lang/svg` package as a dependency in your `elm-package.json`. Run `elm package install elm-lang/svg` in the project directory.